# Can I use a 32:9 aspect ratio monitor on an android TV PC?

Tags: external-display, screen-resolution

I have several TX92 TV PCs connected to TVs for streaming, and to monitors for use as thin client workstations with Windows. I recently upgraded, getting the same android box for each use. What I want to do with the one where I do my work, is buy and connect a 49 inch 32:9 aspect ratio monitor. I have several questions. Can I do it? Will the aspect ratio magically appear in the list of available aspect ratios in android settings? I use "Resolution Changer" (google play) to change resolution and DPI for phones, TV PCs, and the BlueStacks emulator for Windows. Can I make the monitor work using that? The TX92 comes rooted from the factory. A 32:9 aspect ratio will let me have two Windows sessions side by side, each 1920x1080, or I can do a Windows session and still have plenty of screen left for android applications. I use "Taskbar" (google play) for the launcher and to run windowed android apps.

Edit:

TX92 has android 7.1.2, 2 gig ram, 16 gig storage.

I don't know what communication exists through the HDMI port. Connecting different devices causes different resolutions to be available in android settings, 4k TV vs monitor. That's why I think the resolution may magically appear when the wide monitor is hooked up.

The TX92 manufacturer has a nice website but has not replied to many inquiries.

Comment: There are a number of questions here and it is difficult to tell what is being asked (beyond an answer of 'just try it and see if it works'). Note that it would help to identify the OS version if you are using physical Android TV boxes. Related developer documentation but describes system behavior: https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html#MaxAspectRatio

Comment: I updated above.

Comment: Yes, having two panels in android 7 will be nice. That's why I want such a wide monitor. May work perfect! The "taskbar" app used as a launcher exploits android windowing very well. It lets me reload another instance of the same app, if the app allows it, resize, use half screen, etc.